# Showing labels inside the jQuery Progressbar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've implement the progressbar successfully http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/#indeterminate

But I need to add the following text inside the progressbar **text 2 (30%)** (see image below)

[image]

I know how to add text in the progress bar(text 1 70%) by
using the following `progressLabel.text( progressbar.progressbar( "value" ) + "%" );`

but I can't find a solution to add text for the right side (text 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/validide/jy3Nq/1/) and see if it's what you need.
It may need a few things fixed :| .

```
<div id="progressbar">
    <div class="progress-label" id="progress-label1">Loading...</div>
    <div class="progress-label" id="progress-label2"></div>
</div>
```

Please do not forget to accept an answer when you find the one you need.